# Mac OS X: Bring GUI applications to foreground when launched from the command line

Tags: macos, terminal

Is there a way to bring GUI applications to the foreground when starting them from within Terminal on Mac OS X? If I run

```
/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit
```

in Terminal, TextEdit opens in the background. This is quite annoying if you're using "make && ./run" when developing GUI applications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least for TextEdit and similar GUI apps, [`open`](http://guides.macrumors.com/open) will work:

```
> open /Applications/TextEdit.app
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to use `open` before, but didn't realize I can open the whole bundle, too. If you use `open /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit`, a new terminal window is launched and the program is again put to the background.

Comment: @jnsg, I'd never thought of using `open` with the executable path. That's interesting behavior. It makes sense, though: If you open an executable from Finder, it will run it in Terminal.

Comment: Is there a way to use `open` or some other command that (a) brings the app into the foreground and (b) doesn't exit once the app is launched?

Comment: Now if only it would inherit the child process's stdout/stderr output streams, then I could use it to spawn a foreground process from Node.js and capture output.

Comment: @SpencerWilliams I just posted an answers for accomplish what you asked for

Answer (score 6):

There seems to be even shorter variant:

`> open -a TextEdit`

Comment: Thank you! So much better than: `open "$(mdfind Minecraft.app | grep Minecraft.app | tail -1)"`

Answer (score 0):

The answers described in this post use `open(1)` with its default options. This has two limitations that might be important in your use case:

- `open` runs the application bundle as a detached process
- `open` does not pipe standard I/O back to your script/shell

To solve these:

- `open` takes a `-W` option for `open` to wait on the application to quit
- `open` takes `--stdout` and `--stderr` option that you can pipe to your shell (or script) TTY

For example:

```
open -W --stdout $(tty) --stderr $(tty) <path/to/Bundle.app>
```

I wrote some more about this here: https://www.jviotti.com/2022/11/28/launching-macos-applications-from-the-command-line.html