# Mac OS X: Bring (non-bundle) GUI applications to foreground when launched from the command line

Tags: macos, terminal

When a GUI process is launched from the OS X terminal, the window shows up in the background, and you have to use command-tab to give it focus.

Is there a way to make the terminal automatically give such GUIs focus after they are launched?
For example (assuming gitk is installed):

`% gitk`

should launch the GUI and then switch to it.

Note: For several reasons, using `open` as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7779521/162094) suggests is not a general solution.

**Update:** To better explain why the `open` method isn't satisfactory, here's a sample bash session (with witty commentary).

```
% cd /my_repo
% gitk
```

Waiting for the GUI to appear ... any day now ... oh wait -- it's already open.  I just didn't notice because it opened a window BEHIND my terminal.  I wonder how long I was going to sit here waiting....

```
% open gitk
The file /my_repo/gitk does not exist.
```

Ah, of course.

```
% which gitk
/usr/bin/gitk
% open /usr/bin/gitk
```

What the ... it opened a new terminal window to run gitk, and it did so in my home directory, not /my_repo, so gitk complains that the current directory isn't actually a repository...

Comment: It might help if you explained more about why you need to invoke a windowed application synchronously from the command line (instead of opening it asynchronously with `open`).

Comment: Not all applications can be opened via `open` (gitk, for example).  Additionally, the ones that can be opened that way will be opened via a separate terminal, which may be inconvenient.

Comment: 'Not all applications can be opened via open' Why not? I can't think of a reason why it would be true--normal/windowed applications by definition should be something you can open from Finder or the Dock. 'will be opened via a separate terminal' I don't understand what you mean by 'separate terminal'. Do you mean that, even if you have a terminal open, you can't use `open ...` from that terminal? If so, why not?

Comment: Sorry for being vague.  I just updated the question.  Hopefully it explains why `open` doesn't quite cut it...

Comment: gitk is doing something strange, acting partly like a GUI app and partly like a command line tool (paying attention to its current working directory).  I think ideally it should take responsibility for bringing itself to the front.

Comment: Thanks, both of you, I get it. It is odd. It should probably activate itself depending on the command-line parameters. If you've given it enough information to perform a complete operation, it should stay in the background, but if you open it for interaction, it should activate. (In general, application should not activate themselves without the user requesting it.)

Answer (score 4):

Do you need to invoke it synchronously? If not, you could start it asynchronously with `&` and then activate it with `osascript -e 'tell application "gitk" to activate'`.

Comment: This worked until macOS Big Sur came along and seems to have ruined it. If I still run the osascript command separately myself from a terminal, it works. But as part of a function where I am invoking the actual tool using `&` and then doing the activate after a delay of `0.5`, it doesn't work anymore. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with gitk specifically you can edit the gitk file to achieve this, I posted an answer on the apple stack exchange: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/74917/35956

You can find the gitk file using the following command from the terminal

```
which gitk
```

In my gitk file I found a line that looks like the following near the top (line 3)

```
exec wish "$0" -- "$@"
```

I changed it to this

```
exec wish "$0" -- "$@" & exec osascript -e "tell application \"Wish\" to activate"
```

When I execute gitk from the command line the gitk window comes to the foreground, another side effect of this is that it executes asynchronously

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap up @chris page's answer in a bash function and drop it in your .bashrc

```
function gitk() {
  command gitk "$@"&
  command osascript -e "delay .5" -e "tell application \"wish\" to activate"
}
```

There should be a way to get rid of the delay by looping and looking for 'wish' with a timeout.

NOTE: 'Wish' is the window title that shows up on my Mac for gitk.

Comment: Does this still work for you with the latest macOS as of today?