# Node.JS - Spawn child process's window on top / in front

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

I am spawning a child process with node, which is an external application on OSX.  The problem is that this external application appears BEHIND the terminal window.  I want this application to appear in the front, on top.

My code looks something like this:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    process = spawn('myApp');
```

The application launches, but it does not show up to the user because it's behind the terminal window. I want it to be in front.

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779454/mac-os-x-bring-gui-applications-to-foreground-when-launched-from-the-command-li) help?

Comment: @Chris thanks for sending that one over.  I played with this  a bit and found that it opened a terminal window and executed the application.  The  terminal window is somewhat undesirable and I was not able to do a SIGINT kill on the child application once it disappeared, which is needed.  I'll continue to play with the options, though.

Comment: "open -a" worked, but I'm still not able to kill the app from my node script...

Comment: I resolved by spawning "killall", which should work for our application.